# I changed my computer resolution and now it shows that the mode is not supported

Tags: display, resolution, safe-mode

I was using my computer (on a samsung tv) and suddenly the resolution changed itself. Then, i tried to change the resolution but then when i did, after waiting it to boot it said that the mode is not supported. I went through the process many people have suggested which is going through safe mode, but when i changed the resolution on safe mode, it immediately also showed that the mode was also not supported. When i tried the other safe modes it immediately said that the mode was not supported, as if the condition is the same with the first safe mode. Please tell me if anyone have an alternative solution other than trying it on a different monitor, because i dont have one.

Please I really need help fixing it.

thank you very much,

kiara.

Comment: So you did have a picture in safe mode? If you get that message it usually means you're either trying a resolution that is to high/has the wrong aspect ratio or your refresh rate doesn't match. What kind of Samsung TV is it an what resolution did you try to set it to?